# iterate complex json data key value and pass to a function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i had a node js app where iam encrypting json data key value using crypto node module.
I had a function to encrypt and when i pass key value to that function iam able to encrypt the value.
If the json is a simple json object my code is working fine.But if the json is complex one e.g., we will have one more json inside a key value where we need to iterate the loop,for this my code is not working.
Not getting idea how to iterate the loop and pass the json key value to the encrypt function.
Can some one help me in this issue.

My git url:https://github.com/harishvarma8055/encryptdecryptapp

```
 var crypto = require('crypto'),
     algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr',
     password = 'd6F3Efeq';

 function encrypt(text) {
     var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
     var crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
     crypted += cipher.final('hex');
     console.log("crypted:" + crypted);
     return crypted;
 }

 function decrypt(text) {
     var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
     var dec = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf8');
     dec += decipher.final('utf8');
     return dec;
 }

 app.post('/encryptdata', function (req, res) {
     var JsonData = JSON.parse(req.body.jsondata);
     var enc = null;

     for (var exKey in JsonData) {
         var encryptData = encrypt(JsonData[exKey]);
         if (enc != null)
             enc = enc + "," + '"' + exKey + '"' + ":" + '"' + encryptData + '"';
         else
             enc = "{" + '"' + exKey + '"' + ":" + '"' + encryptData + '"';
         var dec = decrypt(encryptData);
         var dc = dc + exKey + ":" + dec;
     }

     enc = enc + "}";
     console.log(dc);
     res.send(enc);
 });
```

Comment: 1. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), 2. What object (simple <-> "complex")? 3. What loop? 4. What does "is not working" mean? 5. Any errors?

Comment: Just encode it and then encrypt: `encrypt(JSON.stringify(someObject))`.

Comment: I mean complex json is like this:{
"policyApplication":{"bankDetails":{"accountName":"sam","sortCode":"123-2323-23","accountNumber":"3244"},
"isEsign":"true"} where we are having json inside key value...

Comment: @HarishVarma, why do you want to encrypt each value separately? Why not encrypt the whole JSON-string?

Comment: yes @Thomas we can do the whole,but the requirement is to encrypt only the key value and then store in db

Comment: you're aware that a nested object is also the value for some key on the outer object? You have to be a bit more precise with the requirements, and you may want to add these requirements to the question, and maybe the reasons for these requirements

Comment: Yes @Thomas i should have been more precise..To be more clear ,in the code above there is an encrypt function.Using that function i should encrypt any kind of json object.But not both key and value ,only value should be passed to that function and get encrypted values as response.For Now if it is plain(normal) json object it is working.but if its nested object it is not working..need help there...Thanks

Comment: Hey @Thomas can u please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108697/encrypt-only-json-key-value-and-get-response-of-whole-json-object-with-keyvalue  .I think i articulated in betterway here my question.can u help me out