# Encrypt only json key value and get response of whole json object with keyvalue encrypted

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion, encryption

Iam trying to encrypt only the key value of json object using nodejs app.Iam using crypto node module.I will pass json object(it can be basic or complexi.e.,inside a value we can again have key value pair) then as response we should get the same json in same format which we give initially,but the key value should be enctyped.
In my code I have an encrypt function which will encrypt the data.Here I should only pass the keyvalue to the function,which iam able to do and get back encrypted data.Iam using for each i.e for(var exKey in JsonData) and passing each key value to function.And again framing it back in to json format using this code.

```
var JsonData=JSON.parse(req.headers.jsondata);
var enc=null;  
for(var exKey in JsonData) {
var encryptData=encrypt(JsonData[exKey]);
if(enc!= null)
enc= enc+","+ '"'+ exKey+'"'+":"+encryptData;
else
enc="{"+'"'+exKey+'"' +":"+encryptData; 
}
enc=enc+"}";
```

This is fine if we are using basic json.But if we are using complex(eg.,inside keyvalue other key value pair) this will not work since we need to see whether we are having such and iterate function.So i made changes to code.

```
function iterate(JsonData)
{
 for(var exKey in JsonData) {
 if (JsonData.hasOwnProperty(exKey)) {
    if(typeof JsonData[exKey]=="object"){
     console.log('"'+exKey+'"'+":"+"{");
      iterate(JsonData[exKey]);
 }
  else
 {
  var encrypted=encrypt(JsonData[exKey]);
  console.log('"'+exKey+'"'+":"+ '"'+encrypted+'"');
 }

 }
 }
  function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password);
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
  crypted +=cipher.final('hex'); 
  return crypted;
  }
```

Now using the function i able to iterate the loop and encrypt the keyvalue and then iam consoling the key and value by adding ",:,{.
For example if am passing json as:

{"brokerLimit":"50","traderType": 
{"insurer":"john","cover":"basic" }, "isSplitPayment":"yes"}
Then on console i'll get

"brokerLimit":"51de"
"traderType":{
"insurer":"0e81dc9e"
"cover":"068fc79922"
"isSplitPayment":"1d8bc7"

So Iam able to go inside loop and encrypt the key value..
But now the thing is I want to get this as response in json format i.e

{"brokerLimit":"51de","traderType": 
{"insurer":"0e81dc9e","cover":"068fc79922" }, "isSplitPayment":"1d8bc7"}

So I need to store the encrypted key value in variable ,also to that i need to add ",:,} to make it in json format.Here Iam facing the issue.If the key has property in json then the key value goes back to function.At that time I think we need to save in temporary variable and then we need to add to another global variable and then keep on adding to global variable...But I couldn't fix the logic..Can someone help me in this..Hope my question is clear.If not reply me.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is `algorithm`?

Comment: The word you're looking for is recursion and not iteration.

Comment: @zaph aes algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just create a new object with the encrypted data, and then use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to generate the JSON string.

Comment: JSON.stringify had worked out.But still left with another issue.Iam able to encrypt only string value (i.e., only the value inside "  " ).But for boolean or number ,it is unable to pass to function..So i think before for each loop we need to convert all the key values to string type and pass to for loop can you help in this.

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify()` for that too, but undefined value will result in an undefined result. You can also specify a function as second argument for specific handling. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify for a reference. For your case it's probably better to JSON.stringify the whole object and then encrypt it. To restore the object decrypt the string and then use `JSON.parse` on it.