# Convert the num or boolean type json object from string type to its original

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

In my nodejs app,I had a json object where it had combination of string,num and boolean type .But the boolean and num type is also represented as string.

```
Eg: `{"name":"sam","age":"24","isMarried":"false"}`
```

Here age and isMarried are num and boolean type but represented as string type.So is there any way,that above json key value type is identified and it gets converted in to respective variable type.i.e to

`{"name":"sam","age":24,"isMarried":false}`.`

Any help appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: JSON object has only two methods, you've a JSON string! The best solution would be to form the JSON string correctly when it is created.

Comment: @Teemu the reason for that is I had a function where i'll pass json to it.But it accepts only string value.So,im converting all to string type..Then the fuction returns backs json after some functionality..Then I want to convert that to its original type

Comment: _If_ the data structure really is as simple as you've posted, you could iterate the object, and directly convert all `age`s to numbers, and all `isMarriage`s to booleans. If the data structure is not regular, writing a parser based on values is a lot more complex.

Comment: @Teemu here i gave sample json data.I'll not have same age,isMarried...Even I'll have complex json structure

Comment: @HarishVarma, so the reason for this is a function that only accepts strings instead of proper types? Maybe you should fix that function instead of trying to deal/parse with the results this function messed up.

Comment: Then I'd focus to fix the function which creates the JSON. Or you can start to [iterate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) ... ANy parser can't solve a case, when you actually need a string like `"1234"` though.

Comment: @Thomas Yes ,the function accepts only string type.what it does is encrypts the key value.So I can't modify the function.So,I'm trying to convert all types to string type before passing to function.Then I had another function which decrypts and returns back the json data.Then I want to convert it back in to original data type.

Comment: @HarishVarma You could include the datatype to strings before encryption, then in decrypting code extract the datatype, and convert to real type.

Comment: @Teemu ok.But I think once it got encryped it will be difficult to extract the data type of json..So only after decrypting Iam trying to change its type to original.

Comment: why don't you just encrypt the whole JSON? instead of playing around with the values.

Comment: @Thomas yes ,even iam thinking the same but the requirement is such that i should encrypt only key value

Comment: @Thomas https://jsfiddle.net/cr4qe1an/1/ Here I mentioned how I was doing .can you look and suugest

Comment: @Teemu https://jsfiddle.net/cr4qe1an/1/

Comment: I knew this thing sounded familiar to me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39054955/6567275, I am not willing to help with this approach, because it's just wrong. It decreases security of the encryption by increasing the attack surface tremendously, and providing hints to the encrypted values, wich further weakens security. That's also the reason I asked (in the other question) for the reasons to do it this way, because I assume it's a complete misunderstanding of encryption and the assumption that multiple encryptions will increase security. But not done this way.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to make sure your actual server returns the correct types since JSON understands boolean and integer.
2. You need to create js function that will take care of that. This is not that easy in JS because it has no tryParse.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr4qe1an/

```
var str = '{"name":"sam","age":"24","isMarried":"false"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);

Object.keys(obj).forEach((x) => {
  if (obj[x] === 'false' || obj[x] === 'true') {
    obj[x] = obj[x] === 'true';
  }

  if (!isNaN(parseInt(obj[x], 10))) {
    obj[x] = parseInt(obj[x], 10); // This is bad, '1abc' will be 1
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks..There I just gave a sample json data..Seeing that example I doubt whether it works for any json object ..Will it work for any json object?

Comment: It will if you modify the function to be recursive for sub-types etc.

Comment: For complex json like this {
  "accounting": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "age": "23"
    }
  ],
  "sales": [
    {
      "firstName": "Sally",
      "lastName": "Green",
      "age": "27"
    }
  ]
}...How it is going to work?

Comment: Well, here is modified version with recursion, however not sure if it's good enough because I just scribbled it w/o much testing. https://jsfiddle.net/g7qt29hg/

Comment: `Boolean('false') === true`!

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Stan Thanks.Here the boolean value is changing i.e,true to false and vice versa...And also one thing why does this not working for decimal numbers?

Comment: @HarishVarma Because parseInt does not parse decimals. parseDecimal does.

Comment: @stan ok.Then how can we make it parse for both int and decimal numbers?

Comment: @HarishVarmaYou can change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a mapper for the keys with the wanted callback for converting the items.

```js
var data = { "accounting": [{ "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "age": "23", married: "true" }], "sales": [{ "firstName": "Sally", "lastName": "Green", "age": "27", married: "false" }] },
    map = [
        { key: 'age', cb: Number }, 
        { key: 'married', cb: function (v) { return v === 'true'; } }
    ];

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
    data[k].forEach(function (a) {
        map.forEach(function (b) {
            if (b.key in a) {
                a[b.key] = b.cb(a[b.key]);
            }
        });
    });
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```